# I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 and now I can't start Windows

Tags: system-installation, data-recovery

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 7.

Now I can't start Windows and all of my data has been lost. It seems like I've deleted everything (by mistake) and uninstalled Windows.

Please tell me how I can recover my lost data!

Comment: This post may help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu - but you may not be able to recover **all** of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo update-grub
```

in a terminal in Ubuntu and restart your computer. An option to boot Windows may then appear when you turn on your machine.